# How to include reference to website using Miktex on windows?

Tags: bibtex

I am following along this tutorial, https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/, to learn a bit of latex. I am unable to figure out how to add a reference to a website in the bibliography. I am using the Texworks editor on windows 10, and the "mode" is set to `pdflatex+makeindex+bibtex`.So here are the relevant sections of my latex code:

In the `hello_latex.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{About cats}
\date{2013-11-20}
\author{name}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \newpage
%... a bunch of stuff
    \paragraph{} Here is an example of a citation embedded in text. Random citation \cite{BOOK:1} embedded in text.
    \paragraph{} Here is an example of an article citation. Yet another random citation \cite{ARTICLE:4} embedded in text.      
    \paragraph{} Here is an example of an "inbook" citation with page numbers mentioned. Another random citation \cite{INBOOK:3} embedded in text.
    \paragraph{} Here is example of a website citation. One more random citation \cite{example} embedded in text.

\newpage
    \bibliography{hello_latex}
    \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\end{document}
```

And in the `hello_latex.bib` file:

```
@BOOK{BOOK:1,
AUTHOR="John Doe",
TITLE="The Book without Title",
PUBLISHER="Dummy Publisher",
YEAR="2100",
}

@INBOOK{INBOOK:3,
AUTHOR="John Doe",
TITLE="The Book without Title",
PUBLISHER="Dummy Publisher",
YEAR="2100",
PAGES="100-200",
}

@ARTICLE{ARTICLE:4,
AUTHOR="John Doe",
TITLE="Title",
JOURNAL="Journal",
YEAR="2017",
}

@MISC{WEBSITE:1,
HOWPUBLISHED = "\url{http://example.com}",
AUTHOR = "Intel",
TITLE = "Example Website",
MONTH = "Dec",
YEAR = "1988",
NOTE = "Accessed on 2012-11-11"
}
```

I have found getting the references to work is very unpredictable for me. On adding the entire set of references at one go, the compilation resulted in errors. So I had to repeat the process one by one for the BOOK, ARTICLE and INBOOK references to work, and finally I have not gotten the WEBSITE reference to even work.

The console output is a mix of warnings I am unable to understand.

```
Undefined control sequence.
l.19 Intel, ``Example website.'' \url
                                     {http://example.com}, Dec 1988.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `BOOK:2' on page 1 undefined on input line 28.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `BOOK:1' on page 7 undefined on input line 178.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `ARTICLE:4' on page 7 undefined on input line 179.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `INBOOK:3' on page 7 undefined on input line 180.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `WEBSITE:1' on page 7 undefined on input line 181.
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `BOOK:2' on page 1 undefined on input line 28.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `BOOK:1' on page 7 undefined on input line 178.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `ARTICLE:4' on page 7 undefined on input line 179.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `INBOOK:3' on page 7 undefined on input line 180.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `WEBSITE:1' on page 7 undefined on input line 181.
```

Comment: Well the first two lines of your error are quite easy to understand: the command `\url` is undefined. You should load the `url` or the `hyperref` package to define it.

Comment: You naturally should also cite it `\cite{WEBSITE:1}` (you are using \cite{example} above).

Comment: If you use `biblatex`,  the `url` field and the  `online` \ entry type are defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from the following lines in the bib file:

```
@MISC{WEBSITE:1,
  HOWPUBLISHED = "\url{http://example.com}",
```

Command `\url` is defined after the call of package `url` or `hyperref` only. You have to load one of this packages in your preamble.

The bib entry key here `WEBSITE:1` is not used when you cite: `\cite{example}` in your TeX code.  Change the key for a valid citation to: `\cite{WEBSITE:1}`.

With the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{BOOK:1,
  AUTHOR    = "John Doe",
  TITLE     = "The Book without Title",
  PUBLISHER = "Dummy Publisher",
  YEAR      = "2100",
}
@INBOOK{INBOOK:3,
  AUTHOR="John Doe",
  TITLE="The Book without Title",
  PUBLISHER="Dummy Publisher",
  YEAR="2100",
  PAGES="100-200",
}
@ARTICLE{ARTICLE:4,
  AUTHOR="John Doe",
  TITLE="Title",
  JOURNAL="Journal",
  YEAR="2017",
}
@MISC{WEBSITE:1,
  HOWPUBLISHED = "\url{http://example.com}",
  AUTHOR = "Intel",
  TITLE = "Example Website",
  MONTH = "Dec",
  YEAR = "1988",
  NOTE = "Accessed on 2012-11-11",
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\title{About cats}
\date{2013-11-20}
\author{name}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{url} % <====================================================

\begin{document}
%... a bunch of stuff
\paragraph{} Here is an example of a citation embedded in text. Random 
citation \cite{BOOK:1} embedded in text.
\paragraph{} Here is an example of an article citation. Yet another 
random citation \cite{ARTICLE:4} embedded in text.      
\paragraph{} Here is an example of an "inbook" citation with page 
numbers mentioned. Another random citation \cite{INBOOK:3} embedded in 
text.
\paragraph{} Here is example of a website citation. One more random 
citation \cite{WEBSITE:1} embedded in text. % <===========================

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

you get the following result without any error(s) while compiling:

[image: resulting pdf]

Of course you have to compile with `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`.

Your error messages

```
l.19 Intel, ``Example website.'' \url
                                     {http://example.com}, Dec 1988.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `BOOK:2' on page 1 undefined on input line 28.
```

have two causes:

1. As explained above, you need to load package `url` or `hyperrref` to get a defined command `\url`.
2. Message `Citation`BOOK:2' on page 1 undefined`means that you missed to call`bibtex hello_latex`to get the bibliography file`hello_latex.bbl`. You can use the terminal/console to type and execute this command or check how your used editor invokes`bibtex` (sorry, I do not use your editor, check the documentation of it).